# Maximums and Ifs in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to find the maximum value from a column using another column as the criteria in Excel. However, I can only get it to return the maximum value out of all of the values in the column without the IF criteria being met. What am I doing wrong? See picture below: Column A has IDs. Column B has hours worked. I want the maximum hours worked for each ID in Column A. Instead I just keep getting the maximum hours from Column B.

[image: Example]

Comment: I am assuming you do not have Office 365 Excel.  You will need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: I would make a list of unique ID's then countif(). Or use large() if these are indvidual and not to be a total per ID.

Comment: ctrl shift enter did the trick - I had to take it out of table formatting and used ctrl shift enter and it worked. Thanks!!